# Why there are different Programs for Windows and MAC and Linux?

Tags: system

The programs are written into the high level language and then that high language is converted into the machine language which are set of opcodes. I want to ask why there are some programs which are compatible to the Windows and some with the MAC because when they are compiled they are simply opcodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because  programs rely on functions already in the OS, like ReadFile or ShowMessage,  and Some OS's have different archtectures so they have different functions.  The actual calculations and stuff is the same

as an example:
Imagine Mac OS has a function called ReadFile.  Windows has a function called GetFile.  Linux has a function called "OpenFile".  When you compile your program, it doesn't include those functions into it's code.  The "op codes" just say "call the function at address #xxxxxx"  So if you did it in windows, the OS will have the GetFile function ready at #xxxxxxx,  so your program will execute.  But if you copy your program to Mac, the OS is set up differently, so there is no function at #xxxxx waiting for you, so the program fails.

In reality, it fails before it gets there because the OS looks at the codes before running them so see if they're compatible

And it's not just functions like "readFile".  Nearly all programs involve getting some memory for your variables, and each OS does it differently (ie, they have a different function at a different address #xxxx to get memory), so you programs cannot run on any other os once they're compiled.

Comment: But in the end they are opcodes for instruction set of processor and the instruction set for each processor is same. then why there are different programs for both OS.

Comment: you're wrong in thinking that each program ends up as a self-contained set of instructions for the processor.  It's only a tiny piece of the instructions.  So you rely heavily on the OS, and different OS's have different functions to call.

Comment: Thats what I am saying OS is also set of instructions executing so why not these instructions can run on any OS. Can you share some link that tells me exactly what is OS

Comment: Think of each OS as one program, running on the processor.  Your own code is just like clicking different buttons and stuff in the OS. It just asks the OS to do some things.   So on a Mac, buttons are in different places, so a program that says "click on the start menu" won't "run" on a Mac

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer I am really thankful to you.

Comment: please upvote and accept it before this question gets closed for being too "general" :)